# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'len'

Tags: string, python-3.x, int

I'm on Python 3.7 trying to measure the length of a binary number converted from a integer. I'm well aware that len() cannot measure BIN or INT so I use STR to make it readable by len().

```
def counter(n):
    return n. len(str(bin(n)[2:]))()
```

However, when I run the code, I get this error.

> File "/home/campagnollo/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/countBits.py", line 2, >in countBits
>      return n.len(str(bin(n)[2:]))()
>
> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'len'

I don't know why it's regarding the object as a INT instead of a STR. When I debugged the line without len(), it comes out as a STR.

Comment: Is the `n.` right after `return` intentional?

Comment: Also the length of a number in binary will be ceil of log-to-base-2 n. That is going via floats so might slightly expensive but should be cheaper than constructing a string. And then there's always the naieve way: d = 1 and increase d while n <= (1 << (d+1)).

Comment: everything between 'return n.' and '()' can be added or changed per the assignment. Nothing else can be added or changed.